# Is it safe to exchange cryptographic salt and initialization vector in messages?

Tags: encryption, aes, initialization-vector, salt

I have a client which does the following:

```
salt = randomBytes(16)
iv = randomBytes(16)

// secret is a user-specified passphrase
key = pbkdf2(secret, salt)

message[0] = salt.toHex() + iv.toHex()
message[1..n] = encrypt('message content', key, iv)

// to notify server that message stream is ended
message[n+1] = end_message
```

I'm wondering if it is safe to send both `salt` and `iv` to the server like this?

The server does:

```
if(count == 0) {
  salt = message[count][0..15].toBytes()
  iv = message[count][16..31].toBytes()
  count++
  return
}

if(message[count] === end_message) {
  log(output)
  count = 0
  output = ''
  return
}

// for every subsequent message until end_message
key = pbkdf2(secret, salt)
output += decrypt(message[count++], key, iv)
```

`AES-256-CTR` is the encryption used.

Comment: As Yehuda Lindell notes below, re-running PBKDF2 for every message is very inefficient. The fewer times you need to run PBKDF2, the less computation time you waste on it (and the more you can increase the iteration count, in turn, making it more secure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. There is no problem with sending the IV in the clear. So, this is fine. Likewise, the salt is not there to add entropy so this is also fine.

Having said that, I understand from the code that the application is not using a uniformly distributed (and so high entropy) key. This is a problem and very bad, since it is easy to carry out a brute-force search over the password space. In practice, this is extremely effective.

The salt helps a little bit since it makes it impossible to prepare a time/space tradeoff attack (often called a Rainbow table attack, since this is one instance of the attack). However, it still will not be secure unless a very high entropy key is used.

Another thing which is very strange (and a bit out of scope so I'll refer to it anyway) is that the server is regenerating the key for every block. This is really inefficient (both the key derivation costs and the key schedule for AES is run every time).

Comment: There is a lot of weird stuff in that pseudocode. ```message[0] = [salt, iv]``` on the sender side, yet ```salt = message[0..15]``` on the server side? Also, salt is only 15 bytes on the client side yet presumably 16 bytes on the server side are read as the salt. Not to mention the strange stuff going on with ```count```.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. Just wondering about the part about not using a uniformly distributed key. The pbkdf2 function generates a SHA1-HMAC hash from the secret passphrase, is that not sufficient? I realise the  pseudo-code can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Or do you mean that I should impose certain restrictions on the user-supplied key?

Comment: The fact that you apply SHA does not give you entropy. The problem is that an attacker can try all possible passwords and see if it gets the correct one (it can check by trying to decrypt and see if it makes sense).